# Doubts MT and Pushdown Automata

Tags: automata

I need help with two questions about Automata. Follow then

1.) build a pushdown automata that recognizes the following language:
L = {a^mb^n / m <= n}

2.) Considering the MT below, give the settings for the **abcab** and **abab** inputs

[image: MT]

Comment: What have you tried so far, and where specifically are you stuck? For 1, do you know how to match the language `{a^b^n}`? If so, how might you modify the PDA for that language into your language `L`? For 2, could you list out the steps you think the machine is taking on those inputs, and point to where you're having trouble?

Comment: After several researches and attempts, today I managed to solve the problem, thank you very much!